# python panda modify csv file not save

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have large file and when I modify this file I try to save the file, but the terminal shows me an error.

```
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas import DataFrame
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 import numpy as np 
 def modifydataset():
      df = pd.read_csv('/home/najeeb/Downloads/stocks_sentdex.csv')

      df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
      df = df.set_index('time')

      del df['id']

      df.to_csv('stocks_sentdex.csv')
 modifydataset()
```

And error shows in the terminal:

```
File "/home/najeeb/PycharmProjects/pandaplotaa.py", line 16
   df.to_csv('stocks_sentdex.csv')
                              ^
  IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: you are mixing tabs and space for indentation

Comment: The line where you get the error `df.to_csv`: you use all spaces for indentation whereas earlier lines use tabs and spaces.

Comment: Recommend you use a good python-oriented editor/IDE. I prefer spyder.

Comment: My editors (Geany and SublimeText) have an option called "display white space", so that you can distinguish spaces (gray dots in my editors) from tabs (gray arrows). Very useful for python.

Comment: Possibly an unclear/unrelated question title?